# HUGE processing speed difference in running apparently similar codes - resulted by using $ instead of a pipe?

Tags: r, pipe, aggregate, operators, pipeline

R newbie here. So I'm running a big df (> 5.7m rows) in R. It has the following `col_names()` columns, and within day_of_week are values like "Fri", "Wed"...you know, the days.

```
 [1] "ride_id"       "rideable_type" "started_at"    "ended_at"      "member_casual" "date"         
 [7] "month"         "day"           "year"          "day_of_week"   "ride_length"
```

At some point I need to see some aggregate stats using the following code:

```
aggregate(ride_length ~ member_casual + day_of_week, data = df, FUN = sum)
```

**result_1:**

```
   member_casual day_of_week   ride_length
1         casual         Fri  9461812 mins
2         member         Fri  5962077 mins
3         casual         Mon  8198659 mins
4         member         Mon  5853290 mins
5         casual         Sat 15505160 mins
6         member         Sat  6303482 mins
7         casual         Sun 13364709 mins
8         member         Sun  5485445 mins
9         casual         Thu  8023285 mins
10        member         Thu  6646226 mins
11        casual         Tue  6859473 mins
12        member         Tue  6300679 mins
13        casual         Wed  6901511 mins
14        member         Wed  6488745 mins
```

I want to rearrange the days in a week, from disorder to normal order (Sun, Mon ... Sat), to make it like this:

**result_2:**

```
   member_casual day_of_week   ride_length
1         casual         Sun 13364709 mins
2         member         Sun  5485445 mins
3         casual         Mon  8198659 mins
4         member         Mon  5853290 mins
5         casual         Tue  6859473 mins
6         member         Tue  6300679 mins
7         casual         Wed  6901511 mins
8         member         Wed  6488745 mins
9         casual         Thu  8023285 mins
10        member         Thu  6646226 mins
11        casual         Fri  9461812 mins
12        member         Fri  5962077 mins
13        casual         Sat 15505160 mins
14        member         Sat  6303482 mins
```

In order to achieve result_2, I tried the following two ways to do that:

**1. With a pipe (%>%):**

```
df$day_of_week <- df %>%
     ordered(day_of_week, levels = c("Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat"))
```

**2. Without a pipe:**

```
df$day_of_week <- ordered(df$day_of_week, levels=c("Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat"))
```

While the first code took more than 1.5 HOURS to run without doing the job (I had to click STOP to interrupt, all the waiting time wasted), the second code only took less than 1 second. Also to make it clearer, I'm using R Studio Desktop and all my data are saved in my PC. So I guess it's not an internet issue.

So I have four sets of questions:

1. Has anyone encountered similar problems? Why the difference?
2. If such a problem is caused by using the pipe, does that mean there are situations where a pipe is preferred, and others where you should steer away from using one?
3. Generally speaking, what is the use of $, when should I use it?
4. After I achieved result_2 for my aggregate() output, I incidentally find my original df is not organized as rows starting by Sun, and then Mon...Actually, the df row order has not changed at all! Why is it? And if I want to arrange my df as my aggreagre() result_2, what should I do instead?

Thanks in advance! Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Suggest also trying the native pipe `|>` in place of the magrittr pipe, the magrittr eaqer pipe `%!<%`, df <- transform(df,  ...)` and `df <- df %>% mutate(...)` .

Comment: Your piped version is sending all of `df` as the first argument of `ordered()`, which is supposed to be a vector, hence the strange behaviour. Try `df <- df %>% mutate(day_of_week = ordered(day_of_week, ...))`

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the replies! @G.Grothendieck Sorry the only pipe I learned so far is %>% and I might be able to understand all the others and their differences some time down the road...

Comment: Hi @AndrewGustar thank you for the reply! I tried out your code and it worked very well! I feel the root cause for such a time difference is within your answer but I'm not very familiar with how vectors work or how software processes. Could you please explain it to me in a plainer way?  :D

Comment: The native pipe transforms `x |> f()` to `f(x)` and then runs it.  The magrittr pipe works differently making use of environments. I don't think that it is the usual case that the magrittr pipe is materially slower but it looks like you have found such a case.

Comment: @Abooboo The important thing you need to remember with piping is that a pipe operator sends the object on the left as the FIRST argument of the function on the right (unless you specify otherwise using named arguments and a `.`). The "time difference" is just the unpredictable behaviour you get if you send a whole dataframe (which is a list of vectors) to a function expecting a single vector.

Comment: @AndrewGustar hmm so my understanding is, while ordered() function only expects a single vector, `mutate()` can process a df? If it's so, I'm not sure how I can distinguish such two sorts of functions in the future. I used to think you can just pipe anything into some functions...If possible can I also ask a potentially relevant question about the difference between `$` and `%>%` real quick? For example in working with the `mpg` data within `dplyr`, you can do `table(mpg$year)` but not `mpg %>% table(year)`. I thought they served in similar way to specify the df used?

Comment: @Abooboo The only sure way to tell is to read the documentation - it is easy to find and (usually) helpful. Also, `mutate` is a `tidyverse` function and designed to work smoothly with piped dataframes. `ordered` is a base-R function, and some of these do not work quite as you might like them to with pipes.

Comment: @Abooboo `mpg %>% table(year)` will not work because `table` (a base-R function) does not take a dataframe as its first argument and a column name as its second, which is what the pipe is doing.

Comment: @AndrewGustar wow...this is deep. Guess I got a lot to learn and memorize...thank you very much Andrew!

Answer (score -1):

Can you try this?

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  arrange(factor(
    day_of_week,
    ordered = TRUE,
    levels = c("Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat")
  ))

# A tibble: 14 × 3
   member_casual day_of_week ride_length
   <chr>         <chr>             <dbl>
 1 casual        Sun            13364709
 2 member        Sun             5485445
 3 casual        Mon             8198659
 4 member        Mon             5853290
 5 casual        Tue             6859473
 6 member        Tue             6300679
 7 casual        Wed             6901511
 8 member        Wed             6488745
 9 casual        Thu             8023285
10 member        Thu             6646226
11 casual        Fri             9461812
12 member        Fri             5962077
13 casual        Sat            15505160
14 member        Sat             6303482
```

Comment: Thanks Tom :) This code managed to re-arrange my original df into "Sun" "Mon"..., but somehow my aggregate() didn't change. Since we're on it, I guess arrange() is to order texts alphabetically and numeric values from large to small/viceversa, while by adding factor() one can make a customized order?

Comment: @Abooboo You want the aggregate () function to output a custom-ordered column (Sun, mon ...)? We would need some sample data then

Comment: Hi Tom, sorry if I haven't made myself clearer. I managed to custom-order my aggregate() output, and changed it from result_1 to result_2 using the second code line in my post. My most aching confusion was why my first code line wouldn't work that well :D